# PyIgnite scan freezes

Tags: python, ignite

I try to scan all values from Ignite cache. I manage to create generator with cache.scan() method but when I want to get next value from generator it freezes.

```
from pyignite import Client

client = Client()
client.connect('127.0.0.1', 10800)
cache = client.get_cache('CACHE_NAME')
all_results_gen = cache.scan()
result = next(all_results_gen) # makes interpreter freeze
```

EDIT:
It may be related that this cache is also used by Java app.

EDIT2: I think it might be something about java types conversion to python. Maybe with sql queries it will be easier to get this values.

Comment: How many entries in this cache? Any errors displayed on server node?

Comment: There should be 29 records so that's not about quantity also there is no error thrown at ignite server

Comment: Can you provide a small reproducer project somewhere?

Comment: Java app creates cache with table for example Measurement. 
While i try to select with pyginite and sql query like client.sql("SELECT * FROM Measurement") it shows that there is no table with this name.

Comment: This sounds like a separate question.

Comment: Maybe its about not using public schema for tables?